# How do you edit the title of a gist when it contains large files?

Tags: gist

I want to change the title of my gist but I get the following message when I try to edit the gist through the webapp:

> This Gist contains files that are too large to edit via the web
>   interface. You can still edit this Gist directly using your favorite
>   Git client.

How can I change the title of a gist that contains large files? I would like to avoid having to delete the large files -> change title -> reupload large files. To my knowledge, the clone of a gist does not give you access to any relevant files to title the gist.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: @Moogs: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could do it was to temporary remove the long files, edit the title and then add them back. I searched around and couldn't find a better way of doing this